# How to handle error response return from server api in kotlin+retrofit+coroutine+mvvm

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

I have two different response from the same endpoint. One being the actual success result data model and one being an error response model. Both json structure like this:

**SuccessResponse:**

```
{
   "result":{
      "id":1,
      "name_en":"Stack Over Flow",
      "summary":"Stack Overflow is the largest, most trusted online community for developers to learn, share​ ​their programming ​knowledge, and build their careers."
   }
}
```

**ErrorResponse:**

```
{
    "message": "Login Failed"
}
```

I can handle the success response but I can't show the error message what I get from the server. I have tried many ways but I can't do this.
Here my I share my some aspect what I did

**MainViewModel.kt**

```
var job: Job? = null
val myDataResponse: MutableLiveData<HandleResource<DataResponse>> =MutableLiveData()

fun myData() {
        job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {

            val myDataList = mainRepository.myData()

            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                myDataResponse.postValue(handleMyDataResponse(myDataList))
            }

        }

    }
private fun handleMyDataResponse(myDataResponse: Response<DataResponse>): HandleResource<DataResponse>? {
        if (myDataResponse.isSuccessful) {

            myDataResponse.body()?.let { myDataData ->
                return HandleResource.Success(myDataData)
            }

        }

        return HandleResource.Error(myDataResponse.message())
    }
```

**I need a solution while server give me error message I want to show same error message on my front side. How can I achieve this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private fun handleMyDataResponse(myDataResponse: Response<DataResponse>): HandleResource<DataResponse>? {
      
      myDataResponse.body()?.let { myDataData ->    
         if (myDataResponse.code() == 200) {                     
           return HandleResource.Success(myDataData )                 
         } else {
           val rawResponse = myDataData.string()                        
           return HandleResource.Error(getErrorMessage(rawResponse))     
         } 
      }
    }


fun getErrorMessage(raw: String): String{   
  val object = JSONObject(raw);
  return object.getString("message");
}
```

The body of the response (be it success or failure) is response.body(). And if you want to get it as a String, then call response.body().string(). Since you want to read message object from the response you need to convert it into Json.

Comment: here is my process `myDataResponse.body()?.let { myDataData ->
   if (myDataResponse.code() == 200) {
                    return HandleResource.Success(myDataData )
                } else {
                    Log.e("Error", "$myDataResponse")
                    Log.e("Error", "${myDataResponse.body()}")
                }
}` 
My log print this message: errorBody: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=403, message=Forbidden, url=http://www.apiurl.com/api/v1/data/}
But my actual error message is: {"error":"No Data Found"} but it's not print

Comment: There is a difference with server error response and server success response  containing your custom error. In the first case the server does not return http status 200 for instance 403, in the second http status is 200 but body contains object meaning error. Based on your comment I can see that you does not receive status 200 so you do not receive `{"error":"No Data Found"}` from your api at all - you end up with first case mention at the beginning. First make sure that your API returns code 200 for successful and unsuccessful log in.

Comment: My api returns 200 code while login success and returns 403 code while login failed or something. I tried your first step but I have show you that's what I got. So please tell me or explain me how can handle it

Comment: Sorry for not understanding in the first place, I updated the response. Hope it helps.

Comment: I am glad that to you for your humble response. Here I share with you my gist link: https://gist.github.com/ahmed-razeeb/20435963cb6267b34b1ad1dc256cc15b
If you find any issue fixed it on your way. Thanks for your support

Comment: Happy to here that, thanks for link. Please mark response as correct.

Comment: make response correct means? I don't understand would you can explain this. you can contact through my email. razeebahmed0[@]gmail[.]com

Comment: Please refer to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

If you are a following MVVM pattern then I suggest to create a sealed class for the API calls.

To handle api success and failure or network issue. **Resource** class is going to be generic because it will handle all kind of api response

```
sealed class Resource<out T> {

    data class Success<out T>(val value: T): Resource<T>()

    data class Failure(
        val isNetworkErro: Boolean?,
        val errorCode: Int?,
        val errorBody: ResponseBody?
    ): Resource<Nothing>()

}
```

on the base repository while calling the API, you can return the resource whether it is success or failure.

```
abstract class BaseRepository {
    suspend fun  <T> safeApiCall(
        apiCall: suspend () -> T
    ): Resource<T>{
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
            try {
                Resource.Success(apiCall.invoke())
            } catch (throwable: Throwable){
                when (throwable){
                    is HttpException -> {
                        Resource.Failure(false,throwable.code(), throwable.response()?.errorBody())
                    }
                    else ->{
                        Resource.Failure(true, null, null)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you follow this pattern you'll be able to handle all the failure and success response, I hope this will help.

Comment: Here is my **SelaedClass**: 
sealed class HandleResource<T>(
    val data: T? = null,
    val message: String? = null
) {
    class Loading<T> : HandleResource<T>()
    class Success<T>(data: T?) : HandleResource<T>(data)
    class Error<T>(message: String?, data: T? = null) : HandleResource<T>(data, message)
}`
how can i implement your new idea?

Comment: If you don't know how to implement it for the API call, please take a reference from this project [androidproject](https://github.com/probelalkhan/android-mvvm-architecture/blob/master/app/src/main/java/net/simplifiedcoding/mvvmsampleapp/data/network/SafeApiRequest.kt)

Comment: Nullable boolean? Please don't.